# What is the formal way of expressing 1990s?

Tags: formality, numbers

How do you express the last decade of 20th century in formal written English? "1990s"? If the century is known from the context, can you simply say "the nineties"?

As in: "The involvement of US in Kosovo in the nineties"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that *the nineties* is formal enough for any context, since it does not detract from a scholarly air.  It would not be preferable to write *the 90s*, though, since it is discouraged to use numerals in formal writing.

Comment: I don't agree that using numerals in formal writing is discouraged. It's common for numbers greater than twelve.

Answer (score 1):

‘The 1990s’ should do for most situations. ‘The nineties’ used to refer to the 1890s, and they were more spefically called ‘the Naughty Nineties’, but I suppose that’s too long ago now to risk any confusion.

Comment: Bearing in mind the "grocers apostrophe", and the fact that lots of people write **90's**, for example, it would probably have been better not to quotate **The 1990s**. Which in practice can be simply **the 90s** because in practically all contexts the century is clear from context.

Comment: Question is: Is "the 90s" formal enough?

Answer (score 1):

*The nineteen nineties* or *The 1990s*